# What is the guarentee of existence of the differentiable function $t=\phi(t^{*})$ in the proof?

Tags: integration, proof-explanation, vector-analysis

> What is the guarentee of existance of the differentiable function $t=\phi(t^{*})$ in
>   the proof?

Reference:*Advance Engineering Mathematics*-Erwin Kreyzig[9 E][page:324]
[image]][click here to enlarge image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF8E0.png)

How does two representation of the same curve relate by a differentiable function $\phi$? I don't understand this line, Rest of the line is fine for me. Please help me.

Comment: I have added extra term differentiable to the question. I request you to note.

Comment: What is a "representation" of $C$? A smooth parameterization?

Comment: yes. It must be smooth parametrization.@anomaly

Comment: How could I write the expression of $\phi$ using known functions?